# Multiple Models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a site that has a Layout with multiple partial views on it. These Partial views have models with a database connected to them. I can display the partial views separately but not on the same layout. I used the code first approach so i have a entities model that has all of my models in it. The database was generated and connected. I have data in the tables and i am currently displaying these in the admin section for editing and deleting etc. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
Here is my layout partial call:

```
    <li>@Html.Partial("_SubCategory")</li>
```

My controller is a list - currently in the auditScheduleController:

```
    public ActionResult _SubCategory()
    {
        return View(_db.SubCategories.ToList());
    }
```

In my partial view i have put a number of senarios and non seem to work. If i put
        `@model IEnumerable<QQAudit.Models.Subcategory>`
I can display the page by itself and get a list of the Subcategories. It faults out if i open it up through the layout. Saying something about

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AuditSchedule_5218AAD34020C54DC3FF0CFD6169988BB5FED2C296ABF80AC3EFFF93441CE91B', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'QQAForm.Models.SubCategory'.

I have looked on different forums and found some things but everything i have tried that is out there seems to fail in some fashion.

The funny thing is my background is Zend PHP and i can do what i am tring to accomplish there but cannot duplicate it in MVC3 C#.

August 01 2012

I am at the point were i want to add the ID of the page to the link I have already changed the global.asax to be:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "AuditSecion", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{section}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "QQAForm.Controllers" }
        );
```

I want the link to  populate the ID that the page is on. So the partial looks like this:

```
@{ Layout = null; }

@model IEnumerable<QQAForm.Models.SubCategory>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

@Html.ActionLink(item.SubcategoryName, "audit", new { id = item.SubCategoryID }, null)

}
```

The subcategoryID should be the section and the ID should be the ID of the page which looks like this.

```
http://localhost:52490/AuditSchedule/Audit/1192
```

in theory the link of the submenu should be

```
http://localhost:52490/AuditShedule/Audit/1192/1
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: OK this is a slightly complicated question. My view has 5 areas. Header, side menu Partial, top area Partial, and bottom area is content Body. I have it now where when on a list of Audits the view populates with the top partial as the record selected. I want that to stay there no matter what is done on the page. The side menu is populated from a table of subcategories that i want to show a form in the bottom or Body of the layout. Right now the string is the record id if i have a menu with a link to change the form per question (which is also in a table, that will change and my audit record.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you're invoking the partial view.  *Html.Partial* requires a view name and a model; since you're not passing a model, it is crapping out. (It seems like you're expecting your code to invoke the action named *_SubCategory*, but it's actually trying to invoke the **partial view** named *_SubCategory*.)  Try passing the model explicitly (if you have it available in your model):

```
@Html.Partial("_SubCategory", Model.EnumerableListOfSubCategories)
```

Alternatively, you can use the *Html.Action* method, which will render the result of an action in your current controller:

```
@Html.Action("_SubCategory")
```

I think the second approach is what you are attempting to do.

Comment: The Action worked.. However i am in some kind of funk because now for some reason my partial views are showing up with a header and footer like i am calling it from a layout. So when i do the partial it shows up where i want it with header and footer included. I am going to shut down visual studio and restart to see if it takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

At the top of your _subcategory view

Comment: Thanks that worked! I am not really sure why i would need to put anything it was not doing it before. Anyway thanks